# How to append specific url param to the redirected URL in nginx

Tags: nginx

In nginx, I am redirecting a URL with a param like:

www.example.com/xyz?var1=ty&var2=po&var3=k  to

www.example.com/anything?a=1&**b=po_k**

in redirectedURL  **b=po_k** is combination of source url var2 and var3 .

Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
rewrite ^/xyz/?$ /anything?a=1&b=${arg_var2}_${arg_var3}? redirect;
```

Note that:

- arguments are taken with curly braces, because `$arg_var2_$arg_var3` would attempt to use `$arg_var2_` which doesn't exist (thus proper escaping needed)
- the trailing `?` will strip existing arguments from the redirect

Comment: Thanks, for the same, along with the clarification. This worked.